# Imagem .png em relatório Jasper

Tags: php, ireport, jasper-reports, fpdf

Estou começando no PHP e para finalizar meu primeiro sistema tenho que fazer um relatório, o mesmo tem umas logos e marcas d'águas, estou utilizando o JasperDesigner para gerar o XML para a lib PHPJasperXML, mais quando mando gerar o relatório as logos e a marca d'águas só aparece quando o mesmo é .jpeg.
O problema de ser .jpeg que quando for impresso o fundo não fica transparente como em um .png, alguém teve esse problema e conseguiu resolver? Sugestões de outras ferramentas...

Answer (score 1):

Passei pelo mesmo problema, então resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
<image hAlign="Right" vAlign="Middle">
    <reportElement style="StyleSeta" x="1236" y="1" width="10" height="16" uuid="5c3ba9a6-9116-47af-b4c8-231df22634e7">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$V{caminhoImagem} + "SetaCrescimentoOperacional.png"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Eu pego adicionei a imagem element no meu relatorio, e no seu image expression eu passo o caminho da imagem dentro do meu projeto, no meu caso a variavel fica:

```
$V{caminhoImagem} = "http://localhost:8080/RelatoriosWEB/
```

E concateno com o nome da imagem `"SetaCrescimentoOperacional.png"`

Então a imagem PNG no caminho: `"http://localhost:8080/RelatoriosWEB/"SetaCrescimentoOperacional.png"` será adicionada ao seu relatorio.